# Vim conceal indentation. Replace indentation spaces with utf-8 chars

Tags: regular-expression, indentation, conceal

I use four spaces for indent. I would like to replace the indentation with some UTF-8 chars.

What I have:

1.

```
def foo(bar):
    for jaffa in bar:
        print jaffa
```

2.

```
var foo = function(bar){
    bar.forEach(function(jaffa){
        console.log(jaffa);
    });
}
```

What I want:

1.

```
def foo(bar):
►for jaffa in bar:
►►print jaffa
```

2.

```
var foo = function(bar){
►bar.forEach(function(jaffa){
►►console.log(jaffa);
►});
}
```

I tried using conceal myself, but I couldn't come up with a pattern to match the indentation spaces.

How would I accomplish changing the indentation to UTF-8 chars using vim conceal as described in the examples?

@Muru gave the answer for this question. But what if I want to conceal the last 'block' of the indentation spaces differently than the ones before it? Example:

```
var foo = function(bar){
►bar.forEach(function(jaffa){
◼►console.log(jaffa);
►});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the following:

```
set conceallevel=2
syn match IndentWS '\v(^( {4}|\t)*)@<=( {4}|\t)' conceal cchar=▶
```

I get:

[image]

The regex `\v(^( {4}|\t)*)@<=( {4}|\t)`:

- uses [very magic](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%0B) `\v`
- matches a sets of 4 spaces ( `{4}`) or a tab `\t`, at the beginning of the line, [with zero width `\@<=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D)
- and then a set of 4 spaces or a tab.

Of course, if you use only tabs or spaces, you can simplify the regex accordingly.

For the update, with:

```
set conceallevel=2
syn match IndentWS '\v^( {4}|\t)+\S@=' contains=IndentEndWS,IndentStartWS
syn match IndentStartWS '\v( {4}|\t)' conceal cchar== 
syn match IndentEndWS '\v( {4}|\t)\S@=' conceal cchar=▶
```

I get:

[image]

Making ends highlight differently would need a region, or contained matches. In this case I used two contained matches, one for general  indentation whitespace, and one for indentation just before a non-whitespace character (`\S`).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. How would I change the last conceal character to a different character to signify that it is the last block of indent. Explanation is added in the question.

Comment: @SriHariRajuPenmatsa see update. If you have further requests, post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

This could be used `call matchadd('Conceal', '\s\{'.&ts.'\}', 10, -1, {'conceal': '►'})`

This uses the `matchadd()` function to conceal parts of your text, which needs a 7.4.500 release or something. This has the advantage, that the `match` functions can override syntax rules, the other way around might not be always possible.

Comment: Interesting. I know nothing about this feature. I'll read it up when I get some time. Thank you.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid concealing spaces inside strings, you can use something like `call matchadd('Conceal', '\(\_^\s*\)\@<=\s\{'.&ts.'\}', 10, -1, {'conceal':'►'})`